# Select specific group of records with GROUP BY and MAX(DATE)

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I am trying to enlist the agencies whose latest date of visit is Yes for each agency in the table, for example;

```
Agency Id   Date of Visit   Passed 
1           8/19/2015       No
1           6/9/2015        Yes
1           2/6/2015        No
2           9/2/2015        No
2           5/11/2015       Yes
2           3/4/2015        Yes
3           9/10/2015       Yes
3           5/11/2015       No
3           3/5/2015        No
4           10/6/2015       Yes
4           5/19/2015       No
4           3/25/2015       Yes
```

The desired result form the table should only be the following because in their latest date they were marked as Yes

```
Agency Id   Date of Visit   Passed 
3           9/10/2015       Yes
3           5/11/2015       No
3           3/5/2015        No
4           10/6/2015       Yes
4           5/19/2015       No
4           3/25/2015       Yes
```

I have tried using

```
SELECT agencyid, max(dateofvisit), passed
FROM tblAgency
WHERE passed = 'Yes'
GROUP BY agencyid
```

But this does not seems to work as it bring all those records from the table which are passed as Yes.

Can somebody let me know if that is possible.

Comment: Does it have to be the last date where they have passed, or should they have passed at some time?

Comment: they must have to be passed into the latest date

Comment: General GROUP BY rule: "If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function."

Comment: Hi @MohsinTester 
I have reviewed your query and concluded that you want select list of agencies where 
(1) Passed='Yes' 
(2) Consider latest Date of visit (i.e. If two records with Passed='Yes' then consider the record with latest Date of visit)

Please confirm the same.

Comment: no, if you look into desired results it is clear that there should be 'Yes' in the latest date of visit no matter what were passed results in the past.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an analytic function to get last value for "passed" column. Then it is easy:

```
select * 
from(
    select 
      agencyid,
      passed,
      first_value(passed) over (partition by agencyid order by dateofvisit desc) last_passed_value,
      dateofvisit
    from tblAgency
)
where last_passed_value = 'Yes';
```

You can also do it only with `group by`s and simple max, but you need some joins:

```
select b.* 
from(
    select 
      agencyid,
      max(dateofvisit) as max_dateofvisit
    from tblAgency
    group by agencyid
) lastentry
join tblAgency a on a.agencyid = lastentry.agencyid and a.dateofvisit=lastentry.dateofvisit
join tblAgency b on a.agencyid = b.agencyid 
where a.passed = 'Yes'
```

Comment: I use as it is but it shows an error that `first_value is not a recognized built in function name`

Comment: first_value is a valid function name. http://www.orafaq.com/node/55 What version of Oracle do you use?

Comment: I am using SSMS 2008R2. Is that function is compatible?

Comment: I don't know what is SSMS 2008R2 but does not seem to be a version of Oracle. I'll ad a SQL standard version.

Comment: well, its SQL server 2008

Comment: well, you tagged it oracle. first query will work in SQL sever 2012.

Comment: yes, but I am in 2008 environment. can you please guide through

Comment: Did you read my answer? There is also a standard SQL version.

Answer (score 0):

with below SQL query I got the expected result.Please reply me your feedback.

```
---create table
DECLARE @tblAgency TABLE
(
    AgencyId INT,
    dateofvisit DateTime,
    Passed Nvarchar(10)
)

---Insert Records
INSERT INTO @tblAgency VALUES(1,'2015/8/19','No')
INSERT INTO @tblAgency VALUES(1,'2015/6/9','Yes')
INSERT INTO @tblAgency VALUES(1,'2015/2/6','No')
INSERT INTO @tblAgency VALUES(2,'2015/9/2','No')
INSERT INTO @tblAgency VALUES(2,'2015/5/11','Yes')
INSERT INTO @tblAgency VALUES(2,'2015/3/4','Yes')
INSERT INTO @tblAgency VALUES(3,'2015/9/10','Yes')
INSERT INTO @tblAgency VALUES(3,'2015/5/11','No')
INSERT INTO @tblAgency VALUES(3,'2015/3/5','No')
INSERT INTO @tblAgency VALUES(4,'2015/10/6','Yes')
INSERT INTO @tblAgency VALUES(4,'2015/5/19','No')

DECLARE @PassedAgency Table
(
    AgencyId INT
)

--Select AgencyId with Passed='Yes' with Latest dateofvisit
INSERT INTO @PassedAgency
SELECT TM.AgencyId FROM @TblAgency AS TM
OUTER APPLY(SELECT MAX(TD.dateofvisit) AS MaxDate FROM @TblAgency AS TD WHERE TD.AgencyId=TM.AgencyId) A
WHERE TM.DateofVisit=A.MaxDate AND TM.Passed='Yes'


--select agency details
SELECT * from @TblAgency AS tbl1
LEFT JOIN @PassedAgency AS tbl2 ON tbl1.AgencyId=tbl2.AgencyId
WHERE tbl2.AgencyId IS NOT NULL ORDER BY tbl1.AgencyId,tbl1.dateofvisit desc
```